# Inequality with Inverse Mills Ratio

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the following:

$ \frac{2f(k)^2}{2F(-k)}<-\frac{f''(0)}{f(0)}, $

where $F(\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot)$ are CDF and PDF of single-peaked symmetric distribution with zero mean.

Any help would be appreciated.